# Lua with the Freebase API

Tags: api, lua

I need to use the [Freebase API](http://freebase.com/api) in Lua, but Google requires you to use SSL.

Lua doesn't have built-in networking support, so I have to use external stuff like `LuaSocket` and 'LuaSec`. The problem is that I can't install them.

I use the ZeroBrane IDE, so I tried downloading and putting them in the `lualibs` directory, following the instructions on the libs' websites. But `ssl.core` and `ssl.context` are missing.

Where can I find them?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssl.core` and `ssl.context` seem to be inside the SSL dynamic library itself. If you are on Windows, all you need to do is to put `ssl.dll` in `<ZeroBraneStudio>\bin\clibs\` folder (`ssl.lua` and `ssl\https.lua` are already included in ZBS install under `lualibs` folder) and you should be able to run the following example (I just tested it):

```
require("socket")
local https = require("ssl.https")
local body, code, headers, status = https.request("https://www.google.com")
print(status)
```

I posted a more complex example that shows configuration and handshake steps here: http://notebook.kulchenko.com/programming/https-ssl-calls-with-lua-and-luasec.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found Your post in many of the hundreds of Google searches I've made.. I feel like a complete idiot, but where does that DLL has to be? I can't find it in LuaSocket 2.0.1 nor in LuaSec

Comment: It used to be referenced on LuaSec wiki, but after it's reorganized, I don't see the link anymore. You can grab it from one of earlier versions of ZBS: https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/archive/0.35.zip (bin/clibs/ssl.dll).

Comment: Thank You sooo much! I'd up-vote You, but got no reputation to do it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Alexander You can accept this as the answer though.